# imap_search problems with Exchange 2010

Tags: php, imap, exchange-server-2010

I've seen hundreds of examples here at Stack Overflow about imap_search, but I cant get it work with Exchange 2010.

```
// This works:
$messages = imap_search(
  $mbox, 'FROM "John Smith"', SE_UID
);

// This doesn't work:
$messages = imap_search(
  $mbox, 'FROM "john.smith@mail.com"', SE_UID
);

// This doesn't work either:
$messages = imap_search(
  $mbox, 'FROM john.smith@mail.com', SE_UID
);
```

I cant rely on the name, I need to be sure that mail is being sent from a specific mailbox. Because John Smith may have different mailboxes. How can I perform that?

Comment: It is impossible to verify "from what mailbox" a message has been sent on the level of the imap protocol. You have to rely on what is stated in the message headers which is something everyone can forge, so put into whatever he/she likes. That is a general thing about email messages. The only real way to verify the sender identity would be to verify a cryptographic signature specified in a message (a signed message). But that is not connected to imap in any way.

Comment: well i meant John Smith may have several boxes, like `john.smith@hotmail.com`, `john.smith@gmail.com` etc

Comment: Sure, I understood what you mean by "mailbox". But as said: what is specified as "From:" inside an email message is free text. You can specify whatever you want to, if you know your way around a bit. Want to receive an email message from putin@kgb.ru and from obama@whitehouse.gov? No problem...

Comment: `john.smith@mail.com` must be stored somewhere, because my SMTP wont accept non FQDN sender. I've tried `FROM "John Smith <john.smith@mail.com>"` and even `FROM "John Smith [john.smith@mail.com]"` none of these work

Comment: Hm, the code looks fine. Maybe an issue with MS-Exchange? It gave me headaches a lot when I still had to use it... As typical for MS products it does not fully support protocol standards. Try contacting their support about the issue if it is your server, then you payed for the support anyway with your licence.

Comment: What about `'FROM "john.smith" "mail.com"'`? Maybe it stumbles over the `@` if it is not escaped? No idea, sorry.

Comment: Whats is the usual output of `$headers = imap_headers($mbox); print_r($headers);` ? Im my case I see only names, but not addresses.  Like this: `[463] =>        464)10-Apr-2015 EaseUS               Get free lifetime license (16974 chars)` Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Might be an effect of html interpretation if you use php via http in contrast to CLI. Try using `htmlescape()`...